# SQL query for user t1, t2, . . . , tm terms in where clause

Tags: java, sql, user-input

User gives String as input of terms they can be `t1, ...tm` now I have to embed these `t1,... tm` in sql where clause. 
Select * from documents where `term = t1` OR `term = t2 ...... term=tm`

At the moment I am splitting string into string array:

```java
String[] terms = term.split("\\s+");     
 for (int i =0; i<term.length; i++) {
     if (i == term.length -1) {
     str += "term = " + term[i];
}
else {
    str += "term = " + term[i] + " OR ";
}
```

Now I am getting

> string str= "term = document OR term = word Or term = explanation".

But term is my column name and document value how can I pass this in where clause of SQL?

Comment: Please edit and post a [mcve]. thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, since you are splitting by spaces, that the user's input is like this:

```
document word explanation
```

First use `trim()` to remove any leading spaces from `term`.
Then inside the `for` loop enclose all the items of the array in single quotes (although this is not the safe way to construct a query, you could use a Prepared Statement and `?` placeholders):

```
String[] terms = term.trim().split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    str += "term = '" + terms[i] + "'";
    if (i < terms.length -1) {
        str += " OR ";
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
term = 'document' OR term = 'word' OR term = 'explanation'
```